# Pull to refresh GridView infinite loading/ fails to pull data

Tags: android, android-view, android-gridview, baseadapter

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong with this, the code is pretty clean/ simple, but for some reason when I pull to refresh, it just shows me the loading icon infinity. Not only that, but I don't even receive any errors. The library I used for pull to refresh is [this one](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, but the fact that it's not even giving me errors is making it very hard for me to track down.

And yes, I am sure the rest request is working.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.Mode;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener2;
import com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public final class PullToRefresh extends Activity {

    static final int MENU_SET_MODE = 0;
    static final String KEY_FEED = "feed"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_UID_FK = "uid_fk";
    static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "last_name";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    static final String KEY_CREATED = "created";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_img";
    static final String KEY_DATA = "data";
    static final String KEY_HOMETOWN = "hometown";
    static final String KEY_BIO = "bio";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private PullToRefreshGridView mPullRefreshGridView;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private GridAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ptr_grid);

        mPullRefreshGridView = (PullToRefreshGridView) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_grid);
        mGridView = mPullRefreshGridView.getRefreshableView();

        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        mPullRefreshGridView
                .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener2<GridView>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPullDownToRefresh(
                            PullToRefreshBase<GridView> refreshView) {
                        Toast.makeText(PullToRefresh.this, "Pull Down!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            new RestClientUsage().getPublicTimeline();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPullUpToRefresh(
                            PullToRefreshBase<GridView> refreshView) {
                        Toast.makeText(PullToRefresh.this, "Pull Up!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            new RestClientUsage().getPublicTimeline();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setText("Empty View, Pull Down/Up to Add Items");
        mPullRefreshGridView.setEmptyView(tv);
        adapter = new GridAdapter(PullToRefresh.this, feedList);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class RestClientUsage {

        public void getPublicTimeline() throws JSONException {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("loggedin_uid", TabHostFragmentActivity.loggedin_uid);

            RestClient.post("http://localhost/basic/rest/request/format/json",
                    params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                        private JSONArray feed;

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
                            try {
                                Log.i("JSON->TRAILS RESPONSE", json.toString(3));

                                // Getting Feed Array
                                feed = json.getJSONArray(KEY_FEED);

                                /*
                                * Log & Debug Code String feed_log =
                                * feed.toString(3); int feed_length =
                                * feed.length(); String string_length =
                                * Integer.toString(feed_length);
                                * Log.i("JSON PROFILE FEED RESPONSE", feed_log
                                * ); Log.i("JSON PROFILE FEED LENGTH",
                                * string_length);
                                */

                                // looping through Feed of Updates
                                for (int i = 0; i < feed.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = feed.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String jFeedObj = c.toString(3);
                                    Log.i("JSON FEED OBJ", jFeedObj);

                                    // Storing each json item in variable
                                    String uid = c.getString(KEY_UID_FK);
                                    String first_name = c
                                            .getString(KEY_FIRST_NAME);
                                    String last_name = c
                                            .getString(KEY_LAST_NAME);
                                    String name = first_name + ' ' + last_name;
                                    String http = "http://10.0.2.2/CI_REST_LOGIN/UPLOADS/thumbs/";
                                    String base_url = c
                                            .getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                                    String thumb_url = http + base_url;
                                    String message = c.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);
                                    String created = c.getString(KEY_CREATED);

                                    // creating new HashMap
                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                    // value
                                    map.put(KEY_UID_FK, uid);
                                    map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                                    map.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
                                    map.put(KEY_CREATED, created);
                                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);

                                    Log.i("Trails - line 130", "Success");
                                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                    feedList.add(map);
                                }

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been
                                // refreshed.
                                mPullRefreshGridView.onRefreshComplete();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(
                0,
                MENU_SET_MODE,
                0,
                mPullRefreshGridView.getMode() == Mode.BOTH ? "Change to MODE_PULL_DOWN"
                        : "Change to MODE_PULL_BOTH");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem setModeItem = menu.findItem(MENU_SET_MODE);
        setModeItem
                .setTitle(mPullRefreshGridView.getMode() == Mode.BOTH ? "Change to MODE_PULL_FROM_START"
                        : "Change to MODE_PULL_BOTH");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_SET_MODE:
            mPullRefreshGridView
                    .setMode(mPullRefreshGridView.getMode() == Mode.BOTH ? Mode.PULL_FROM_START
                            : Mode.BOTH);
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my `GridView` adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public GridAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label); // title
        SmartImageView thumb_image = (SmartImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
        update = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        name.setText(update.get("name"));
        thumb_image.setImageUrl(update.get("thumb_img"));
        name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

        private int position;
        private String clicked_uid;

        public myOnClickListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
            update = data.get(position);
            Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
            clicked_uid = update.get("uid");
            Log.d("Clicked UID:", clicked_uid + "");
            Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                    TabHostFragmentActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("profile_uid", clicked_uid);
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should POST to 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost in the call to `RestClient.post` in `RestClientUsage`.

I am not familiar with`JsonHttpResponseHandler`, but I would image there's an `onFailure` method (or something similar) that you may want to override.  If there is, you may way to call `mPullRefreshGridView.onRefreshComplete()` in it.

Comment: Wow....Wow, i feel so dumb.Thank you very much for pointing that error out to me.the RestClient uses : https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

and ive edited the request to hide my actual api calls, but you're right i did forget the localhost/ 10.0.2.2 thing :X .  It still doesnt work as is unless i add " 

adapter = new GridAdapter(PullToRefresh.this, feedList);      mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);     mPullRefreshGridView.onRefreshComplete();  "


is there a way i can clear the old adapter each time a user pulls down OR rig it to add only new list items?

Comment: If you add some sort of update method to your GridAdapter, you should just need to call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after the update to get the GridView to update.